# does GetDiskFreeSpace API considers folder quota?

Tags: windows, msdn, quota

`GetDiskFreeSpace` API from MSDN: does it consider quota while returning free space?

For example, if E:\ drive has 50GB free space, and I have a folder which has 10Gb hard limit, now if I use this API to get the free space on the folder, how much is it supposed to return? 10GB or 50GB?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both `GetDiskFreeSpace` and `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` take folder quotas into account.

**NB:** according to the documentation for `GetDiskFreeSpace`, querying a non-root directory is not supported.  I suspect the documentation is just out of date, but as a precaution it would be safer to use `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` which has no such restriction.

Note that the `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` function returns both the number of free bytes available to the user (taking user quotas and folder quotas into account) and the total number of free bytes.  If you want the number of free bytes available to the user, use `lpFreeBytesAvailable` and if you want the total number of free bytes (ignoring quotas) use `lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes`.

Comment: As far as I know `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` only operates on volumes and shares (drive letter, mounted volume and UNC roots) and when given a full path it just looks for said root.

Comment: @Anders, I tested it before posting my answer (Windows 7 and 2008 R2) and it definitely takes folder quotas into account.  So does `GetDiskFreeSpace` for that matter.  It didn't work on Windows XP if I remember rightly.  I'm not entirely sure about Vista/2008.  (Although the link in your answer says this was fixed in Vista.)

Comment: The non-Ex version is probably limited to roots, it's the only thing you had on Windows 95. It is also limited to 2GB so it is not really useful anymore. Not really sure how you tested the non-Ex version on a folder if it only accepts roots?

Comment: @Anders, somewhat to my surprise it accepted non-root directories (despite what the documentation says) and took folder quotas into account.  And because it returns the number of clusters rather than the number of bytes it isn't limited to 2GB.  All the same, I don't see any point in using it nowadays, given that `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` is so much easier. :-)

Comment: I guess it depends on the Windows version, older versions used to be capped because some apps calculated the sum with 32-bit math. You cannot even trust the cluster and sec.per.clu. geometry numbers because Windows would tweak them so the cluster count was within the FAT16 limits.

Comment: As to `GetDiskFreeSpace`, it no longer enforces passing a root directory, which never mattered in NT anyway. Both versions open a handle to the target directory and call `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile`. `GetDiskFreeSpace` queries the [`FileFsSizeInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540282) and `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` queries the [`FileFsFullSizeInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540267), which expands the former's `AvailableAllocationUnits` into `CallerAvailableAllocationUnits` and `ActualAvailableAllocationUnits`.

Comment: @eryksun, I tested FSRM folder quotas.  I haven't tested NTFS volume quotas (we don't use them) but the documentation says they work.

Comment: Root paths are enforced in 2000 for the non-Ex version, any valid path seems to work in XP. I did not check if the [SMB v1 bug](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2006/09/26/why-disk-space-is-incorrectly-reported-on-folders-where-file-server-resource-manager-quotas-are-enabled/) applies to Vista if you somehow turn off SMB v2.